# What is the difference between 完了 and 終了?

Tags: word-choice, usage

Both 完了 and 終了 seem to have the connotation of finished/complete, but what is the difference, if any, in usage?

Comment: A few have hinted at it, but no one has clearly distinguished 完成 from these two either. How does it differ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

完了 *kanryō* means "completed", while 終了 *shūryō* means "ended".

> 式典の準備は完了した - The preparations for the ceremony are complete.
>   祭りは夜更けになってようやく終了した - The festivities finally came to an end late at night.

Answer (score 19):

The video game Star Fox 64 uses 作戦完了 when you fulfill your mission objective, and 作戦終了 when the mission is over but there's some objective you haven't fulfilled. The English version translates these as "Mission Accomplished" and "Mission Complete", respectively. So perhaps 完了 suggests some kind of fulfillment, and 終了 is more neutral.

Comment: Hahahaha.  I **immediately** thought of Star Fox 64 when I saw this topic!!!  I haven't played the game in a long time, but I though the two completion messages were 作戦完成 and 作戦完了?  I've always been confused between 完成 and 完了, and my memory tells me this game is to blame.  DO A BARREL ROLL!!!

Comment: I just double-checked using YouTube videos. The game definitely uses 作戦完了 and 作戦終了 exactly as I described. Perhaps you're thinking of another game?

Answer (score 3):

I think 完成【かんせい】 has the meaning "completed" with the nuance "Well done!" But, I'm not positive.